# Similarity relations on sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations, set-partition

Good evening,

I am reading Hazel and Humberstone's "Similarity Relations and the Preservation of Solidity", a paper that has the aim of defining, starting from partitions and equivalence relations, what could a set resulting from a similarity relation on might look like.

There are two points not really clear to me regarding the very first section.

1. "Note that because a similarity relation need not be transitive, an element of U can belong to more than one similarity class, by contrast with the case of equivalence classes. Thus in solving our problem, the desired notion of an X will not require, as that of a partition does, that the sets it contains should be pairwise disjoint."

I don't really get why transitivity and not other properties in equivalence relations are directly responsibile of the fact that equivalence classes are pairwise disjoint and also why relations that are reflexive and symmetric, but not necessarily transitive, do not imply analogous similarity-classes that are pairwise disjoint.
I think a good idea would be to find a counter-example, but i couldn't manage to do so

2)" As a first stab toward a solution, which will soon be seen to require further
refinement, we introduce the notion of a decomposition of U , by which is meant
a collection $\Delta$  of non-empty subsets of U such that

a) the union of all the elements of$\Delta = U$

b) for no x,y in $\Delta$ we have $X\subset Y$

Condition (i) is required if decompositions are to be sets of similarity classes for
a similarity relation S, because of the reflexivity of S, and condition (ii), which
replaces the condition of pairwise disjointness in the definition of partition, is
needed because similarity classes are maximal amongst the S-solid subsets, so one
cannot be properly included in another, for which reason the same should go for
the components of a decomposition, as (ii) dictates."

Here i did not understand why refelxivity is responsibile for the fact that the union of the elements in the decomposition is equal to the origina set.

Thanks in advance.

source: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/225877517_Similarity_Relations_and_the_Preservation_of_Solidity

Comment: I don't understand your question.  You ask for an example of a nontransitive relation?  Fine... let the elements of the set be numbers and let the relation be $x\sim y\iff |x-y|<1$.  That is the relation is "they are within distance $1$ of each other."  Here you have $1\sim 1.75$ and that $1.75\sim 2.5$ but $1\nsim 2.5$

Answer (score 1):

For your first question, let $R=\{\langle m,n\rangle\in\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z:|m-n|\le 1\}$; then $R$ is reflexive, symmetric, and not transitive, and the similarity class of $n\in\Bbb Z$ is $[n]_R=\{n-1,n,n+1\}$. Thus, each $n\in\Bbb Z$ is in three similarity classes: $[n-1]_R=\{n-2,n-1,n\}$, $[n]_R=\{n-1,n,n+1\}$, and $[n+1]_R=\{n,n+1,n+2\}$.

For your second question, let $x\in U$. Reflexivity implies that $\langle x,x\rangle\in R$, so $x\in[x]_R$, and therefore $x$ is in the union of the similarity classes of $R$. Thus, $U=\bigcup_{x\in U}[x]_R$.

**Added:** Let $U=\{a,b,c,d,e,f\}$, and consider the decomposition

$$\Delta=\big\{\{a,b,c\},\{a,c,d,e\},\{d,e,f\},\{a,c,f\}\big\}\,;$$

we want to know whether $\Delta$ could be the set of similarity classes of some similarity $\sim$ on $U$. Suppose that they are. Each of them must be $\sim$-solid, so we know that

- $a\sim b$, $a\sim c$, and $b\sim c$;
- $a\sim c$, $a\sim d$, $a\sim e$, $c\sim d$, $c\sim e$, and $d\sim e$;
- $d\sim e$, $d\sim f$, and $e\sim f$; and
- $a\sim c$, $a\sim f$, and $c\sim f$.

Combining those results, we see that

- $a\sim c$, $a\sim d$, $a\sim e$, and $a\sim f$;
- $c\sim d$, $c\sim e$, and $c\sim f$;
- $d\sim e$ and $d\sim f$; and
- $e\sim f$.

That is, the set $\{a,c,d,e,f\}$ is also $\sim$-solid, and it is not a subset of any member of $\Delta$. In fact, it properly contains three of the members of $\Delta$, $\{a,c,d,e\}$, $\{d,e,f\}$, and $\{a,c,f\}$, which are therefore not **maximal** $\sim$-solid sets: each of them can be expanded to the set $\{a,c,d,e,f\}$. Since $\Delta$ has at least one component that is not a **maximal** $\sim$-solid set, $\Delta$ is not the set of similarity classes of any similarity relation.

We could have recognized this without listing all of the $\sim$-pairs implied by $\Delta$ by noticing that each two-element subset of $\{a,c,d,e,f\}$ is a subset of some component of $\Delta$: $\{a,c\}$ is a subset of $\{a,b,c\}$ (and of $\{a,c,d,e\}$ and $\{a,c,f\}$, for that matter); $\{a,d\}$ is a subset of $\{a,c,d,e\}$; and so on. Because each component of $\Delta$ is $\sim$-solid, every pair of elements of a component are $\sim$-related, so this tells us that every pair of elements of $\{a,c,d,e,f\}$ are $\sim$-related and hence that $\{a,c,d,e,f\}$ is also $\sim$-solid.

To rule out this kind of decomposition, the authors add the following condition: if $Y$ is a subset of $U$ such that each pair of element of $Y$ is contained in some member of $\Delta$, then $Y$ is a subset of some member of $\Delta$. That was not the case with this example: each pair of elements of $\{a,c,d,e,f\}$ is a subset of some member of $\Delta$, but $Y$ is not a subset of any member of $\Delta$. Then in their Proposition $2.2$ they show that this restriction is exactly what is needed to ensure that a decomposition really is the set of similarity classes of some similarity relation.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. There's another point that remain unclear and it is the one I specified in the other answer. If you had the time toclarify it, that would be of great help clarify!

Comment: Thank you a lot. Could the authors have written that for a decomposition to be a set of similarity classes, it is necessary that if there is a set that  is S solid for the fact that for every x and y in that set, then x and y belong to a set of the decomposition, then the set is not a superset of any set of the decomposition?              In another sense, is writing that the set in question must be included or equivalent to a set of the decomposition the same things as writing that it does not have to be a superset of any member of that decomposition?

Comment: @PwNzDust: No, that’s not strong enough: the original decomposition in Example 1.3 satisfies that condition but is not the set of similarity classes of any similarity relation.

Comment: Ok thanks. In order to show that the proposition "If Delta is a set of similarity class,then the condition  Q for Delta is true", can we rely only on the counterexample or do we have to prove that assuming the antecedent, negating the consequent and then arriving to an absurd?.                                            For instance, if we assume that Delta is a set of S solid Xes, and there is an S solid Y not included in any X, does this directly lead me to say that necessarily  Delta is as an X that is not maximal? Sorry for the exercise verbosity.

Comment: @PwNzDust: That result is actually proved in the paper, so you can see how it’s proved; if I remember correctly, it’s Cor. 2.3.

Comment: Thanks, I will check that. Shouldn't the proposition that I asked about be the same as the only if part of proposition 2..2 : isn't that a way to formulate "Delta is a set of similarity classes only if the condition Q for Delta is valid"? In that case, the authors say that this necessary condition is such due to the discussion in section 1, but I still don't get if it is so because of the example of a decomposition for which the condition does not hold, or if it has to be proven linking the fact the t the S solid set we find, in respect to the decomposition, is not a subset of any X

Comment: What I mean more plainly is:"Suppose a generic decomposition is a set of similarity classes, but there is an S solid set that is not a subset of any member of the decomposition. How does the second part of the statement affect the fact that then the decomposition in question can't be a set of similarity classes? If I am correct, how does the fact that the new s solid set is not included in any set of the dec. implies that the dec. is not a set of maximal similarity classes?

Comment: @PwNzDust: If you have an $S$-solid set that is not a subset of any member of the decomposition, then the decomposition is not the set of similarity classes of $S$.

Comment: Thanks, again. Does this condition derive from the fact that we want our set to be made of maximal s solid sets or does it depend on the fact that we want our decomposition to contain ALL the similarity classes, such that "if a set has as members all the similarity classes, then given an X in that set, any subset of X is S solid, and so there can't be a set that is S solid and not equal or included in any X?

Comment: @PwNzDust: We want it to be the set of similarity classes of some similarity relation. Since similarity classes are by definition maximal with respect to the similarity, it must satisfy condition (ii), and since for a similarity $S$ every $S$-solid set is a subset of some similarity class, we need it to satisfy (Q) as well.

Comment: Ok, so the reasoning would be as follow? "The analogous X to the concep of partition must be the set of all similarity classes for a given sim.relation S, such as a partition is the set of all equivalence classes for an eq. relation R. If X is the set of all the similarity classes, every s_solid W must be included in one of the members of x. Then Q is a necessary condition for X. In this case I started with the assumption that X must be the set of ALL AND ONLY similarity classes of a relation S, for analogy with partitions and certain eq. Relations. Is this way of putting the reasonin correct?

Comment: @PwNzDust: That’s the right endpoint, at least; I have the impression that the authors got there by tinkering with the definition until it had the properties that they wanted. One of the most important of those properties is the bijective correspondence between quasi-closed decompositions and similarities that mimics the bijective correspondence between partitions and equivalence relations.